# Set Default Form Values from API Call

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-http

I get the following error when I try to initiate form control values in my ngOnInit method:

**Error**

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

**Method**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getBusinessData().then((response:any) => {
        this.businessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'business_name': [response.data.business_name, Validators.required],
            'email': [response.data.email, Validators.required]
        });
    });
}
```

I was able to get around this by using the setValue after returning a promise from my API service call like so and it works:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        // Build the form
        this.businessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'business_name' : ['', Validators.required],
            'email'   : ['', Validators.required],
        });
        // Fetch data for the view
        this.getBusinessData().then((response:any) => {
            this.businessForm.setValue({
                business_name: response.data.business.business_name,
                email: response.data.business.email
            });
        });
    }
```

But doesn't seem to be the best way. How should I be binding data returned from an API to the form controls? It seems like I shouldn't use formGroups and possibly just use ngModels to bind data to the forms?

**UPATE:**
with micronyks method, I tried the following:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        // Bind data to the form
        this.getBusinessData().then((response:any) => {
            this.businessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                'business_name' : [response.data.business.business_name==undefined?'': response.data.business.business_name, Validators.required],
                'email' : [response.data.business.email==undefined?'': response.data.business.email, Validators.required]
            });
        });
    }
```

But it returns the following error in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in edit.template.html:12:10 caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

This seems to happen when it gets wrapped around the API call. Is the value of **this** being overwritten?

Comment: is it working? if so, do you just want to know best way?

Comment: @micronyks my second method works, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. I feel there has to be a better way than running the setValue method on the formGroup object. Is there a way to bind the data inside of the formBuilder constructor after a promise is resolved from my API call? I keep getting the error stated above when I try to

Comment: I haven't tried this before but you can try this :  `this.businessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'business_name' : [response.data.business.business_name==undefined?'':response.data.business.business_name, Validators.required],
            ...
        });`

Comment: I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Now you don't need to use `setValue` method. just grab data that promise returns and use it as shown in above comment (you can assign custom object whose grab response data). If it works, let me know.

Comment: @micronyks thanks, please see my update above!

Comment: I think its not working.

Comment: In your first code block, you have Validators.required twice after 'email'. That may be causing the errors as it's trying to use a synchronous validator as an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `this.businessForm` instance before angular2 renders view.
Solution_1: Use *ngIf to show form only after you set instance of formBuilder.
Solution_2: Set formbuilder `this.businessForm` with default values and then update your form when you get response from API.